# Minkowski sum of a circle and ellipse

Tags: euclidean-geometry

What will be the Minkowski sum of a circle and ellipse?

Will it be an ellipse of the major axis (a+r) and minor axis (b+r) centered at the location of (x+y), where x is the center of the circle of radius r and y is the center of the ellipse?

Comment: It will not be an ellipse. Think of an extremely thin ellipse. The sum looks like half-disks at each end and a rectangle in the middle.

Comment: Is there any law in the literature which gives some bounds over the shape of a sum of these two?

Comment: Try searching for "parallel curves", for example here, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipseParallelCurves.html.